# GUI не исполняется в onPreExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Неправильно описал проблему. Сначала проходят вычисления `AsyncTask`, которые почему-то грузят основной поток, только потом исполняется `progressDialog show()` и `dismiss()`.

Comment: Не совсем понял вашу проблему. Вы можете показать соответствующий код?

Answer (score 1):

[View.post(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable))

и

[Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

пробовали?