# Android: движение кнопки (анимация в потоке)

Tags: android, java

На Java и Android ранее не писал

```
Thread t = new Thread(new moveButton());
    t.start();

public class moveButton implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(blo == true)
            {
                blo = false;
            }

            imageButtonMove.setX(imageButtonMove.getX() + 1);
            Log.i("LOG", Float.toString(i));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Приложение компилируется, запускается, но как только открываю вид с этой функцией, приложение завершается с этой ошибкой:

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: В Андроиде для анимации есть свои отличные инструменты, и погуглив по запросу "Android animate button" можно это все найти, и не изобретать велосипед

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка ведь сама за себя говорит, что нельзя не в UI потоке производить махинации с UI

если все-таки хочется, то посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/256125#256126)